Laravel Sanctum and Nuxt Auth Utils
I've started project with Laravel and Nuxt3.
But I can't use nuxt-auth-utils with sanctum. It doesn't work.
I try login, laravel return token then it processes another request - https://ecommerce.loc:3000/api/_auth/session and return {} and it dosen't authenticate.
            const login = async () => {
                await $fetch('https://ecommerce.loc/api/login', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: {
                        email: form.email,
                        password: form.password,
                    },
                }).then(async (data) => {
                    fetch();

                    toast.add({
                        color: 'green',
                        title: 'User logged in successfully',
                    });

                    // router.push('/admin');
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)

                    toast.add({
                        color: 'red',
                        title: err.data?.message || err.message,
                    })
                })
            }

I tried to use documentation. But i don't find any information about using nuxt-auth-utils with sanctum.
